# Как собрать многомерный массив на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо создать многомерный массив на js.
Есть html структура, по которой я прохожу `each` и в массив `newArr` добавляю данные. Проблема начинается тогда, когда в `each` вызываю `each`, получаю данные и хочу их записать в массив.

```js
var activeBlock = $('.block').find('.inner');
var newArr = [];
activeBlock.each(function(index, element) {
  blockName = $(element).find('h2').text();
  newArr.push({
    name: blockName
  });
  checkedBlock = $(element).find('.child');
  if (checkedBlock.length > 0) {
    checkedBlock.each(function(i, checkedElement) {
      valChecked = $(checkedElement).find('input').val();
      newArr[index]['check'][i].push(valChecked);
    });
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>первый</h2>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="10">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="20">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>второй</h2>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="30">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" value="40">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>третий</h2>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" value="50">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="60">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (checkedBlock.length > 0) {
    newArr[index]['check'] = [];
    checkedBlock.each(function(i, checkedElement) {
      valChecked = $(checkedElement).find('input').val();
      newArr[index]['check'].push(valChecked);
    });
  }
```

```js
var activeBlock = $('.block').find('.inner');
var newArr = [];
activeBlock.each(function(index, element) {
  blockName = $(element).find('h2').text();
  newArr.push({
    name: blockName
  });
  checkedBlock = $(element).find('.child');
  if (checkedBlock.length > 0) {
    newArr[index]['check'] = [];
    checkedBlock.each(function(i, checkedElement) {
      valChecked = $(checkedElement).find('input').val();
      newArr[index]['check'].push(valChecked);
    });
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>первый</h2>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="10">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="20">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>второй</h2>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="30">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" value="40">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>третий</h2>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" value="50">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="hidden" value="60">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Делал то же самое, только из-за своей невнимательности newArr[index]['check'] = []; добавлял внутри второго each. Спасибо тебе, добрый человек

Comment: @Максим пожалуйста )